# Display very large image by downloading image tiles , I must keep the image high quality.

Tags: android, image, tiles, split

I'm facing an issue on processing very large images(some image have size A0).Currently i'm doing this by split the image to many tiles(size 128x128 pixels ) in difference zoom level and host them on a server for downloading and displaying on the view . I think its mechanism like Google Map . Although i try to improving many times but the View isn't smooth enough for scrolling,zooming,... As far as i know on iOS there is a CATiledLayer class that help developers much on the same work as i'm doing.Could you give me some advises?i really stuck on this task for a long time :(
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hmm, if you already have the tiles, Google Maps allows you to use them as your own tiles with GMaps. Not sure how to do this on Android, though: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays